# Reshaping Array: Linear Regression Group By

Tags: python, arrays, group-by, jupyter-notebook, linear-regression

Unable to outout data from function, looking to return a group by prediction (by ClientID).

The error is around the array which I have been trying to reshape to work.

```
def model(dfTotal3, target):
    y = dfTotal3[['Steps']].values
    X = dfTotal3[['WeightDiff']].values
    X = X.reshape(X.shape[1:])
    X = X.transpose()
    return np.squeeze(LinearRegression().fit(X, y).predict(target))

def group_predictions(df, target):
    target = dfWeightComp[['DTWDG']].values
    return dfTotal3.groupby('ClientID').apply(model, target)

group_predictions(dfTotal3, dfTotal3['DTWDG'])
```

The error from this is:

```
ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 10 into shape (1,)
```

However when I swap in 10 for 1, I get the following error:

```
ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 10 into shape ()
```

I am looking for a dynamic solution as my dataset grows, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What shape is `X`? (What's the value of `X.shape`?) And what shape do you want?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so we can help you figure out what's going on.

Comment: Hi Jakube, when I xshape = X.shape
print(xshape) it prints: (37, 1)

Comment: Hi Simon, Should I include the data I am using?

Answer (score 0):

The below code works for this solution:

```
def model(dfTotal3, target):
    y = dfTotal3[['Steps']].values
    X = dfTotal3[['WeightDiff']].values
    X = X.reshape(-1, 1)
    return np.squeeze(LinearRegression().fit(X, y).predict(target.reshape(-1, 1)))

def group_predictions(df):
    predictions = df.groupby('ClientID')['PredictedSteps'].apply(list)
    df_steps = pd.DataFrame(columns=['ClientID', 'Steps'])
    for client_id, steps in predictions.iteritems():
        df_steps = pd.concat([df_steps, pd.DataFrame({'ClientID': [client_id], 'Steps': [np.mean(steps)]})], ignore_index=True)
    return df_steps

print(df_steps)
```